Excel with Pivot throws 'Root element is missing.' in 7.0.x but not in 6.2.8
We have a complex Excel workbook which contains a Pivot table, macro's and external links. After upgrading to EPPlus 7.0.x we experience issues. A simple statement like
var xl = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\myFileWithPivot.xlsx"));
var dummy = xl.Workbook.Worksheets.Count();

throws  'Root element is missing' in 7, but not in 6.
By removing the pivot table, the issue goes away, but that's surely not what we want.
We've tried various versions of EPPlus to determine which is the breaking change. It turns out 6 works, but any 7 version (tried up to 7.0.9) fails.

I think this is an issue that you should report to the library developers.
